# ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000016835AEE3D0>

Tags: string, tf-idf, valueerror

why do i get this error message: ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000016835AEE3D0>. i dont understand please help me..

````
import ast

def convert_text_list(text):
    texts = ast.literal_eval(str(text))
    return text

TWEET_DATA["tweet_list"] = TWEET_DATA["tweet"].apply(convert_text_list)


print(TWEET_DATA["tweet_list"][90])

print("\ntype : ", type(TWEET_DATA["tweet_list"][90]))```
````

Answer (score 0):

It has been some months since you asked, so you might have found the answer for yourself, I got this problem yesterday, all you have to do is to get rid os every "null" value in the dataset.